# Splitting a class file

Tags: document-classes, input

I am writing a class file and I use a lot of constants (length, colours, strings…) that I would like to take out of the `cls` file for cleanliness. I have tried

```
\ProvidesExplClass{textbook}{2015/05/23}{0.1}{A class for typesetting textbooks}
\input{textbook_consts}
```

the constants being in `textbook_consts.tex` in the directory of `textbook.cls`. Of course it doesn't work: upon using `\documentclass{textbook}` the file tries to input a file in *its* directory.

To be precise, the structure of the development directory is

```
.
├── test
│   ├── test.tex
│   └── textbook.cls -> ../textbook.cls
├── textbook.cls
└── textbook_consts.tex
```

`test.tex` being where I use `\documentclass{textbook}`.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: Rule of thumb: Don't use underscores in filenames. Package `grffile` can help, but a sane naming-scheme seems to be a better idea.

Comment: @Johannes_B That doesn't seem to be the origin of my issue, but I am curious: why should I avoid that, and which name would you suggest?

Comment: @Johannes_B Underscores in file names for TeX input files should not pose a problem (unless the underscore was changed to an active character, for example). Package `grffile` is for graphics files only (`\includegraphics`).

Comment: Several classes/packages use such an approach, but usually assign the extension `.def` to the input file. So long as `textbook_consts` is in a place where TeX is able to find `textbook.cls`, there should be no problem.

Comment: Add a symbolic link also for `textbook_consts.tex`

Comment: Instead of using \input{} in the document, have you tried using it in the *.cls file itself? And, if you must have an underscore in the file name, you could try \begingroup \catcode`\\_=12 \input{textbook_conts.tex} \endgroup.

Comment: If the file with the constants is one directory above, it should be linked as well.

Comment: Make sure that `$TEXINPUTS` is set accordingly then you do not need symbolic links. Rather than using `\input` for `textbook_consts.tex` I would call this file `textbook_consts.sty` and use `\usepackage{textbook_consts}`

Comment: @egreg That worked for my development settings. IIUC, for a local install, I would have to put both the .cls and the .def in `~/texmf/tex/latex/textbook/`, am I right?

Comment: You don't *have* to put them both there but that would make sense. If you wanted to, you could put, say, the `.def` in `~/tex/latex/definitions/` but that would not necessarily be very sensible. But you want it somewhere it can be found.

Comment: @Evpok Yes, that's right.

Comment: @egreg Can you post an answer, then? If not, I'll do it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @cfr Okay, thanks. It seems I'll have to do my homework about `texmf/`.

Comment: I meant `~/texmf/tex/latex/definitions/`.

Answer (score 4):

For testing purposes, you can simply make a symbolic link to `textbook_consts.tex` just like you do for the class file.

In the upper level you can keep as many versions of the class file and of the definition file, provided you have symbolic links pointing to the most recent version (or the one you want to test). So you could have

```
├── test
│   ├── test.tex
│   ├── textbook.cls -> ../textbook.cls
│   └── textbook_consts.tex -> ../textbook_consts.tex
├── textbook.cls -> textbook-0.02.cls
├── textbook_consts.tex -> textbook_consts-0.02.tex
├── textbook-0.01.cls
├── textbook_consts-0.01.tex
├── textbook-0.02.cls
└── textbook_consts-0.02.tex
```

However, the most followed tradition is to give `.def` to such auxiliary files. I'd avoid underscores, though, because at least one package changes its category code. Not a big deal, though, because usually packages are loaded later than class files.

When you are finished with the development, you can put the relevant files in a `textbook` directory under one of the main trees:

```
<TREE>/tex/latex/textbook/
```

The `<TREE>` can have (for TeX Live) three meanings:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
~/texmf
```

referring to the main tree, the local tree and the personal tree.

Adding non distributed files to the main tree is discouraged, because you'll lose reference to them with upgrades. Adding files to the local tree requires running `mktexlsr` (and the files will be available to all users of your machine), while this is not needed for additions to the personal tree.

Note that the personal tree is `~/Library/texmf` when MacTeX is used.

On Windows boxes running MiKTeX the personal tree and the local tree are not available by default (see [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex)).